# What does this ter'angreal do?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In Wheel of Time book 8, *The Path of Daggers*, Elayne is investigating the *ter'angreal* found in Ebou Dar when:

> And then there was the crimson rod that felt hot. Hot, in a way.
>
> Sitting on the edge of her bed at an inn called The Wild Boar, she examined the smooth rod by the light of two polished brass lamps. Wrist-thick and a foot long, it looked like stone, but felt firm rather than hard. She was alone; since the helmet, she had tried to do her studying away from the others. The heat of the rod made her think of Fire...
>
> Blinking, she opened her eyes and sat up in the bed. Sunlight streamed in at the window. She was in her shift, and Nynaeve, fully dressed, stood frowning down at her. Aviendha and Birgitte were watching from beside the door.
>
> "What happened?" Elayne demanded, and Nynaeve shook her head grimly.
>
> "You don’t want to know." Her lips twitched.
>
> Aviendha’s face gave away nothing. Birgitte’s mouth might have been a little tight, but the strongest emotion Elayne felt from her was a combination of relief and — hilarity! The woman was doing her utmost not to roll on the floor laughing!
>
> The worst of it was, *no* one would tell what had happened. What she had said, or done; she was sure it was that, by the quickly hidden grins she saw, from Kinswomen and Windfinders as well as sisters. But no one would tell her! After that, she decided to leave studying the *ter’angreal* to somewhere more comfortable than a inn. Somewhere definitely more private!

Do we ever find out what this crimson rod *ter'angreal* does? Perhaps in a chapter from Nynaeve's or someone else's point of view? Or does it remain forever an embarrassing secret?

Comment: If I'd heard this question nearly a decade ago, I could have probably answered this....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It got her drunk. Like, ridiculously black-out-level drunk.

Jordan was asked about this particular incident a few times at *Path of Daggers* book signings/promotional chats, and he claimed that he would probably write more about it later. We do subsequently get a quote from Elayne that is almost certainly a reference to this incident. This is from *Winter's Heart*, the chapter called "A Lily in Winter":

> Suddenly she grinned, and spread her arms expansively. “Lead me to this oosquai of yours, Aviendha. I don’t know about you two, but I intend to get drunk enough to ... well ... to take off my clothes and dance on the table. And not a hair drunker.”

Aviendha and Birgitte crack up at this, while Min gets very confused. The implication is that channeling into the crimson rod made Egwene so drunk, she stripped and danced on the table in front of the rest of the Kinswomen, then passed out and forgot everything.

Comment: I'd like to think the reader is meant to imagine whatever they wish for this.

Comment: You're more than welcome to fill in whatever addtional details you want; this is just the most likely explanation for what *the author* was thinking when he wrote it :)

Answer (score 3):

@Mikeedenfield answer is correct and here is some quotes from jordan that lead us to agree with mikes assessment on the quote.

> **LARA BEATON** I asked at the signing on Saturday. The exchange went
>   something like this:
>
> What happened with Elayne and that warm ter'angreal?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**
>
> (laughs) What do you think happened?
>
> **LARA BEATON**
>
> We figured it must be some sort of One Power sex toy.
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**
>
> (laughing harder) I may write something about that in a later book.
>
> **LARA BEATON**
>
> RAFO, right?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**
>
> Exactly.
>
> **FOOTNOTE**
>
> This was clarified further in Winter's Heart, 'A Lily in Winter'.

[quote 4](http://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=ter%27angreal%20elayne)